# ToneJS error with AudioContext on newly updated angular8 from angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing a music app with angular and tonejs and everything worked fine until I updated the angular cli from angular 7 to 8 some time ago.

Now I'm getting the following error in the console. 
[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'listener' of object '[object AudioContext]']

But only if I build (ng build) the app and upload everything to the server. With the Development Server (ng serve) everything works.

Does someone have the same problem? Thanks in advance.

I'm using the typescript typings for tonejs. If I import the tonejs script through html I get a different message. I also updated every dependancy.

The error code inside the generated js file is:

```
t.Context.prototype._defineProperty = function(e, n) {
   t.isUndef(this[n]) && Object.defineProperty(this, n, {
      get: function() {
         return "function" == typeof e[n] ? e[n].bind(e) : e[n]
      },
      set: function(t) {
         e[n] = t // error is here on the t
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: check how does look the code generated by build you have it in error stack trace

Comment: I added the error code above.

Comment: are you using ivy renderer? Is this problem occurring for some simple Audio playing example? Can you create simplified example on stackblitz (we will have to download it from there so it can actually be github or some other repository but whatever you prefer)?

Comment: I have create test example it looks like it builds correctly without errors https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zs1m7i

Comment: thanks for the code. actually everything works fine in the live preview mode (with localhost). The error occur only if I build the project. I try to replicate the error inside stackblitz. Maybe the typescript to javascript compiler is the problem?

Comment: it may be the problem because it looks like something is converting some of WebAudio native implementations at least from mine point of view

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed the problem.

@Xesenix I saw that you're using tonejs@13.8.17 in stackblitz so I upgrated my tonejs@13.4.9 manually.

If you start the website where tonejs is running you see the version of tonejs in the console. In the live preview mode the correct version (tonejs@13.8.17) was shown, but when I build the project and upload everything to the server the old version (tonejs@13.4.9) was still shown.

So I cleared the angular cache and build again and now it works perfectly.

Thank you for your help.

PS:
I don't think the angular 7 upgrade to angular 8 made the error.